# Calling my own JavaScript functions

Tags: krl

This problem only manifests itself when my app runs through the KBX. Running it in a bookmarklet works fine. I used to be able to do this, but it doesn't work any more.

Here's what I have. There's an `onclick` attribute on a `<p>` tag that calls a JavaScript function:

```
<p conclick="window.a163x134_log(this); return false;"></p>
```

Here's what my function looks like:

```
emit <|
    window.a163x134_log = function(obj) {
        // Do something
    };
|>;
```

I've tried using a regular function name (not attached to `window`) and namespacing it with `KOBJ`. Neither of those works. The error message I get reads "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'a163x134_log'".

Is this a bug or do I need to change something in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are running into a sandbox issue. Javascript running in the UBX runs in the sandbox separate from the page.

I have a blog post that may or may not be out of date http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2011/03/kynetxs-new-sandboxed-browser-extensions/

You should also try using the 'use resource' to pull in a javascript file. I believe that gets pulled into the page and not the sandbox.

Also see [Kynetx app not working when installed via KBX extension on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653090/kynetx-app-not-working-when-installed-via-kbx-extension-on-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Mike's answer is the most general, but I'm posting my specific solution here for future reference.

The `use resource` didn't work for some reason. So instead, I dynamically add a `<script>` tag in an `emit` like this:

```
emit <|
    var trigger_click_script = document.createElement("script");
    trigger_click_script.src = "<url to my JavaScript file>";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(trigger_click_script);
|>;
```

That external JavaScript file then looks like this:

```
$("p.ttt-time").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something
});
```

This way, we're attaching the click event handler directly with jQuery, rather than relying on the `onclick` attribute being able to see a function with a name.

Note: The site I'm working on has jQuery already available, so I'm using their version, not the `$K` version that come with the Kynetx runtime.